# Vanilla select2 empty data

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

```
<div class="custom d-flex" id="myselects">
<select class="step-select rounded-0 select2" id="jsmd" name="md">
<option value="" disabled="true" selected>Search...</option>
</select>
</div> 

<script>
  const element = document.querySelector('.select2');
  const choices = new Choices(element);
</script>
```

Hi all, I tried the select2 jquery, it works fine. But I wanted to use the select2 vanilla version (choices.js). Problem, I don't get the data the dropdown is empty.

I work with symfony, #jsmd retrieves my data

Comment: The dropdown is not empty. The only option that you have is _Search..._ and that is getting displayed. See https://jsfiddle.net/f4jogpes/ ... if you are expecting other values, your problem must be placed on somewhere else. If your problem is that you can't select an option, make sure that `disabled="true"` is removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ` #jsmd ` call some option with the another JS. With jQuery, I have no problem, but with vanilla yes. I wonder if it is not the execution time that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, and as I suspected. I had a JS file that was running too early. Two solutions

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    jsfunction();
});
```

or

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    jsfunction();
});
```